# How to change the amount of increment when dragging the slider in Properties panel?

Tags: units

After I changed `Length` under `Units` in `Scene Properties` from `Meters` to `Millimetres`, I found a problem when adjusting the value in other property panels (such as the `Extrude` property in my case, shown in the following screenshot) by dragging it horizontally. The increment remains at 10mm-wise, and 1mm while holding `shift` key. So my question is how to change the pre-set drag increment to, for example, 1mm at a time and 0.1mm while pressing `shift` key?

I was changing `Extrude` by dragging. However, it changed 10mm at a time and 1mm at a time when pressing `shift`.
[image: I was changing Extrude under Geometry]

I am using Blender 2.9.3.

Comment: But I found ppl (using 2.9x) on YouTube can do that. https://youtu.be/YEa7lJxsyDk?t=133

Comment: You need to also change the Unit Scale in the Scene Units properties (set it to 0.01)

Comment: Thanks!! Problem solved. I set it to 0.001 at the end. Thank you very much!